# How can set the column as a primary key with serial type?

Tags: postgresql, index

In my postgresql:

```
select index from sample;
index
---------
1
2
3
1
2
```

How can set the column `index` as a primary key with serial type for table `sample`?And the selected value should be as below:

```
select index from sample;
index
---------
1
2
3
4
5
```

I have tried to add it as primary key:

```
alter table sample add primary key (index);
ERROR:  could not create unique index "sample_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (index)=(1) is duplicated.
Time: 1.580 ms
```

How can delete all the value in field `index` ,and assign a continuous range or serial value to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these Steps:

1. Add new column sort_id in sample table.

   alter table sample add column sort_id serial;
2. Drop column index from sample table.

   alter table sample drop column index;
3. Rename column sort_id to index in sample table

   alter table sample rename column sort_id to index;
4. Add Primary Key.

   alter table sample add primary key(index);

Comment: note that the use of serial [is discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) in favour of standard compliant `identity` columns.

Comment: The index is in the first column ,as your way, the index column will be at the last (most right-side) column,how to make it at the first line then?